# Prove that if $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ and contains $c$, then $\int_{c}^{c} f = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The hint is that $\int_{a}^{b} f = \int_{a}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{b} f$.  So I though that if we were considering $\int_{c}^{c} f $, we could say $\int_{c}^{c} f = \int_{c}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{c} f $.  If we then subtract $\int_{c}^{c} f$ on both sides, we are left with $\int_{c}^{c} f = 0$.  Is this an acceptable way to handle this proof?

Comment: I suppose this is fine.

Comment: Another way to do it is $$\int_a^b f = \int_a^c f + \int_c^c f + \int _c^b f = \int_a^c f + \int_c^b f$$
which immediately implies what you want (using Riemann integrability on $[a,b]$)

Comment: @NicholasStull Nice answer, a similar one is $\int_a^c f = \int_a^c f + \int_c^c f$.

Comment: I suppose I should post it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: This seems more like a definition than something you prove. I mean Riemann integration deals with partitions of intervals and it would be weird to partition a point